# How to debug Maven dependent project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application and a Spring Boot library which is added as a dependency to the application. I want to debug that library from the Spring Boot application. Earlier I had library as a Maven dependency but I couldn't reach the breakpoints and then I removed the Maven dependency and instead added the library source code in the work space and kept it as project dependency which as well didn't work. Please help.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the Maven dependency of the spring boot library and copied the source code of the same to some other location.

Please note this location.

I expanded that library jar from the Maven dependencies present in the class path in Eclipse. There is Source option where I attached the copied source code of the library.